# UICollectionView Display oldest post first, i want it to display latest post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

```
var posts = [Post]()
....
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt   indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCollectionViewCell
cell.postTextView.text = posts[indexPath.item].caption
cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "photoplaceholder.jpg")
let urlString = posts[indexPath.item].photoUrl
let url = URL(string:  urlString)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ data, reponse, error     in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else{
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            cell.postImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        })

    }

}
 task.resume()
return cell

}
}
```

I would like to display the latest post instead of the oldest post.
While for tableview, posts[indexPath.row].caption gives me the latest post, 
for UICollectionView it does not, it gives me the oldest post. I would need help on how to get the latest post displayed first before the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There should't be any difference in the order of data between `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`, so you should probably investigate *why* it's happening, and not how to fix it in `cellForItemAt`.

But to answer how to fix it there; since I see you only have a single section, you could simply do `posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].caption` and `posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].photoUrl`

Comment: Great this solved the problem i faced: posts.reversed()[indexPath.row].photoUrl